# Computational Complexity - 1^n + n^4 + 4n + 4

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory

Could someone please explain what the correct answer should be:

Question = What is the complexity of 1^n + n^4 + 4n + 4?

Options = Exponential, Polynomial, Linear, Constant

My interpretation:
Answer should be exponential, because law of addition for O() is that the answer is the dominant term, which imo would be 1^n aka c^n (c = constant) aka exponential. But the answer is wrong and I don't get it :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well 1^n is always 1. Therefore, `1^n + n^4 + 4n + 4` can be simplified to `1 + n^4 + 4n + 4`. Consequently, `O(n^4)`.

So the correct answer is Polynomial.